# Is a Poisson model appropriate when the response are Poisson rate parameters

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-regression, ratio

I am familiar with modelling count data with Poisson regression, for example for count responses $Y_i$ which are random variables with distribution $\operatorname{Pois}(\mu_i)$ with means $\mu_i$ such that $\ln(\mu_i)$ is a linear combination of covariates $x_n$.

Is it still suitable to use Poisson regression, if the responses $Y_i$ now Poisson rate parameters instead of counts?

Comment: Do you mean actual population rate parameters ($\mu_i$) or *estimates* of rate parameters ($\hat{\mu}_i$)?

Comment: I mean estimates of the rate parameters. If I had actual rate parameters then it becomes a curve fitting problem, right?

Comment: You know the sample sizes or exposure times for each of the rate parameter estimates? And they're each just scaled counts?

Comment: I do not know the sample sizes or exposure times, but I know that they are the same for each estimate. I don't understand what you mean by scaled counts.

Comment: Poisson random variates are counts. To generate an estimate of a Poisson parameter from a count you'd either be dividing by another count (the number of time periods observed) or an exposure time (how long observed). Either way the result is a count divided by a known constant, i.e. a scaled count

Comment: right, thanks. The Poisson random variates are for number of counts per event, each event spans the same amount of time.